# Why is my iPad connecting to S3 and using lots of bandwidth?

Tags: networking, ipad, ios, amazon-s3

I noticed my connection has been extremely slow lately at some random times. I figured someone in my house was torrenting, so I booted up `tcpdump` on the router. What I found out is that it appears that *I* am the culprit.

My iPad is uploading at about 80 kB/s (which is my maximum upload speed) and completely saturating the network:

```
09:23:51.414956 IP s3-external-1.amazonaws.com.https > My-iPad.53293: . ack 19082635 win 61472
09:23:51.421163 IP My-iPad.53293 > s3-external-1.amazonaws.com.https: . 19124395:19125835(1440) ack 5762 win 16384
09:23:51.421498 IP My-iPad.53293 > s3-external-1.amazonaws.com.https: . 19125835:19127275(1440) ack 5762 win 16384
09:23:51.449702 IP s3-external-1.amazonaws.com.https > My-iPad.53293: . ack 19085515 win 61472
09:23:51.453923 IP My-iPad.53293 > s3-external-1.amazonaws.com.https: . 19127275:19128715(1440) ack 5762 win 16384
09:23:51.454259 IP My-iPad.53293 > s3-external-1.amazonaws.com.https: . 19128715:19130155(1440) ack 5762 win 16384
09:23:51.484554 IP s3-external-1.amazonaws.com.https > My-iPad.53293: . ack 19088395 win 61472
09:23:51.487558 IP My-iPad.53293 > s3-external-1.amazonaws.com.https: . 19130155:19131595(1440) ack 5762 win 16384
09:23:51.488039 IP My-iPad.53293 > s3-external-1.amazonaws.com.https: . 19131595:19133035(1440) ack 5762 win 16384
09:23:51.521405 IP s3-external-1.amazonaws.com.https > My-iPad.53293: . ack 19091275 win 61472
09:23:51.525480 IP My-iPad.53293 > s3-external-1.amazonaws.com.https: . 19133035:19134475(1440) ack 5762 win 16384
09:23:51.525816 IP My-iPad.53293 > s3-external-1.amazonaws.com.https: . 19134475:19135915(1440) ack 5762 win 16384
09:23:51.558379 IP s3-external-1.amazonaws.com.https > My-iPad.53293: . ack 19094155 win 61472
09:23:51.561336 IP My-iPad.53293 > s3-external-1.amazonaws.com.https: . 19135915:19137355(1440) ack 5762 win 16384
09:23:51.561816 IP My-iPad.53293 > s3-external-1.amazonaws.com.https: . 19137355:19138795(1440) ack 5762 win 16384
09:23:51.593105 IP s3-external-1.amazonaws.com.https > My-iPad.53293: . ack 19097035 win 61472
09:23:51.596258 IP My-iPad.53293 > s3-external-1.amazonaws.com.https: . 19138795:19140235(1440) ack 5762 win 16384
09:23:51.596737 IP My-iPad.53293 > s3-external-1.amazonaws.com.https: . 19140235:19141675(1440) ack 5762 win 16384
```

I unplugged the iPad, and it stopped uploading. When I plugged it in again, it started again.

My guess is it's uploading something to Apple (who must be using S3), but I can't find any information about that on Apple's site or elsewhere online.

What's it doing, and how can I either stop it or throttle its bandwidth to a more reasonable limit (anything over 60 kB/s completely saturates my network).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by backups to iCloud, Apple's cloud storage service. While I can't find any official information from Apple, [some sites](http://thenextweb.com/microsoft/2011/06/08/is-icloud-running-on-microsoft-amazon-cloud-services/) are reporting that Apple is using both Azure and S3 to store iCloud data.

I've not found any way to limit the bandwidth through the device itself; limiting the throughput on the router seems to be the only way to throttle it<sup>1</sup>. It can be turned off completely in the iCloud settings.

Backups are only done while connected to USB power (for power-saving reasons), which is why unplugging it stopped the backup.

<sup>1. Theoretically it should be possible to throttle only to a certain host (S3) but I went ahead and just throttled the iPad's bandwidth to all hosts</sup>